# Solve: $yy''= (y')^2 (1 + \ln y)$

Tags: calculus

Solve a differential equation: 
            $$yy''= (y')^2 (1 + \ln y)$$
a) as an equation that does not contain x,

b) using the change: $y = e^z, z = z(x)$

Comment: Rewrite $\dfrac{y''}{y'} = \dfrac{1+\ln y}{y} y'.$

Comment: As you are asked, make $y(x)=e^{z(x)}$ and now transform the derivatives to work with $x(z)$

Answer (score 0):

After simplifications we get
$$(y'(x))^2+\log(y(x))(y'(x))^2+y''(x)y(x)=0$$ substituting $$v(y)=y'(x)$$ we get
$$v(y)\left(-y\frac{dv(y)}{dy}+v(y)+\log(y)v(y)\right)=0$$ so we get the cases
$$v(y)=0$$ or
$$\frac{dv(y)}{dy}=\frac{v(y)+\log(y)v(y)}{y}$$ and we obtain
$$\int\frac{v'(y)}{v(y)}dy=\int\frac{\log(y)+1}{y}dy$$
Can you finish?
The result is given by $$\log(v(y))=\frac{\log^2(y)}{y}+\log(y)+C$$
$$y(x)=\exp \left(\sqrt{2} \text{erf}^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2
   \pi } c_1 x+\sqrt{2 \pi } c_2 c_1}{\pi
   }\right)\right)$$

Comment: Why should i do this?